# Express update a certain html field

Tags: node.js, express

I have created a simple page that you login with a service and it gets the accounts username using nodejs. I then give the user a file that look like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Hello <span id="user">user-placeholder</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.js: (assume user is logged in as they are)

```
app.get('/authorized', functiong(req,res){
    console.log(accountInfo.username);
    res.sendFile(file);
});
```

I just want to update the `span` that has id `user` with `accountInfo.username`. 
I'm not sure how exactly to update this value.

Comment: Updating static HTML is not a good idea. Use templates, which address the need of dynamic data. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html. Pug is a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a template engine like `pug` by running:

```
npm install pug --save
```

Then you `index.pug` in the views directory

```
html
  body
    span Hello
    span= user
```

Then modify your route little bit to look like this:

```
app.get('/authorized', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { user: accountInfo.username });
})
```

For more details https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html